# Phantom Margin of 90px being applied to the body of my web page?

Tags: html, css

Whilst creating the login page for my site i added a margin of 90px to the login form div (with the id of 'LogIn') to allow it to sit clear of the header. 
this process works for all the other pages of my site, but doesn't for this one?

The problem is that the entire body is given a margin of 90px from the top of the window instead of just the LogIn div?

**It seems to be line 7 of the login.css** that is causing the problem as when i delete it everything goes back to normal, but the login form is still hidden by the header.

Any help is much appreciated, and please do ask if you need any more information!

Also here's a link to the site if you want to see it in action:
http://jakehowell.me/login.php

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flash Crash</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="png" href="../assets/favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="script" href="../script/validate.js">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id= "header">

       <h1>Flash Crash</h1>

            <a href="../index.php" hreflang="en-gb" >Home</a><a href="../login.php" hreflang="en-gb" >Login</a><a href="../feedback.php" hreflang="en-gb" >Feedback</a> </div>
                <div id="LogIn">
                    <h1>Log into Flash Crash</h1>
                    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="../php/login.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                    <div class="login-field">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
                        value=''  >
                                            </div>

                    <div class="login-field">
                        <input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>

                        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Log In</button>
                        <a id="forgotPW" value="forgotPW" action="http://www.google.com/">Forgot Password</a>

                    </form>
                </div>        
                    <div id="DroppingBox">
                        <p>New to Flash Crash? <a id="Drop">Create an Account</a></p>

                         <div id="SignUp">
                            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                            <form id="signupform" name="signupform" method="post" action="../php/create-account.php">

                                <input id="signup_firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                                <input id="signup_lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                                <input id="signup_username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
                                <input id="signup_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                <input id="signup_confirmpassword" type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">

                                <input id="signup_email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="80" size="30">
                                <input id="signup_contactnumber" type="text" name="contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number" maxlength="30" size="30">

                                <button id="signup_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",sans-serif; 
min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 22;
    margin: 0px;
}

h2{
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0px;
}

h3{
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-size: cover;
}

#header {
    padding: 0 50 0 0;
    margin:0;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #ffbb00;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 90px;
}
#header h1 {
    padding: 0 0 0 5;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-size:80px;
    color: #00a1ff;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#header a {
    padding: 0 25 0 25;
    margin:0;
    transition: background .5s;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header a#selected {
    background: #ff9f00;
    cursor: default
}

#header a:hover {
    transition: background .5s;
    background: #ffaa00
}
```

login.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#LogIn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20 10 100;
    margin-top: 90px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #292f33;
}

.login-field {
    display: block;
}

#LogIn input{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 10 0;
    padding: 5;
    width: 350;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#forgotPW {
    color: #1b95e0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15;  
}

#DroppingBox {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 10 0 10 100;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13;
    color: #666;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#DroppingBox a {
    color: #1b95e0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#SignUp {
    display: none;
}

#SignUp input[type="text"], #SignUp input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    clear: right;
    margin: 0 0 5 0;
    padding: 5;
    width: 350;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/*#SignUp input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    clrar: right;
    margin: 0 0 5 0;
    padding: 5;
    width: 350;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#SignUp input[type="submit"] {
    float: left;
    color:red;
}*/

.error {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.errortext {
    display: inline-block;

    color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    #LogIn {
        padding: 0 10 1 10;
    }

    #LogIn input[type="text"]{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #LogIn input[type="password"]{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #DroppingBox {
        padding: 5 10 5 10;
    }

    #SignUp {
        padding: 0;
    }

    #SignUp input[type="text"], #SignUp input[type="password"] {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: That‘s called collapsing margins - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `float: left` on your `#LogIn` div:

```
#LogIn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #292f33;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This works!
It's always something simple, although do you have any idea why, without the 'float: left' it was affecting the whole body of the site?
Thanks a lot for the solution, that saved me a lot of head scratching!

Comment: Your html structure is not really good its just an hard fix. You can check some documentation about floating element here https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: ah i thought this could've been the problem, i'm using PHP files that i made for a few different websites on this, any advice on how to clean it all up?

Comment: I advice you to use Bootstrap. Reset your project and use http://www.initializr.com/ I think it's a good point for HTML beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Change #LogIn to remove the top-margin:

```
#LogIn {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* margin-top: 90px; causing problem */
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-bottom: none;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #292f33;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, 
but if i take that line out, the login form under the header will just remain under the header, rather than in view.
Also this still doesn't explain why this is happening to the whole body of the web page when the margin of 90px is defined as the id #LogIn

Any ideas?